# ReactJS | Make onClick and onFocus call same method only once in total

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that uses `onClick` and `onFocus`. Both of the events call the same function that loads data from an API.

When the user is tabbing through elements on the page and lands upon this component's child `textarea`, `onFocus` runs and loads data from an API.

However, when the user clicks on the component's textarea child, both the onClick and onFocus events try and load data from the API. I want to prevent both events from firing a function twice.

I do NOT want to put events on the text area itself if possible.

```
  function DataRow(props) {

      function focused(e){
          props.loadDataFromAPI(); /* This will get ran twice if clicked on tr element's textarea */
      }

      return <tr onFocus={focused} onClick={focused} ><textarea></textarea></tr>;

  }
```

As you can see, I want it to get called when the user clicks on the tr as well as clicks/focuses on the textarea. I just  don't want that duplicate call when clicking on the textarea!

Comment: you could try setting a boolean in your state called isFetching. When you want to fetch data check first if this bool is true or false. If true then do nothing, else, just fetch your datas as you normally would. on finally put the bool to false to be able to fetch again if needed !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement a `debounce` system to avoid this behaviour.
In this way not only you will avoid this double event firing, but you will prevent user to spam you and polling request if he starts to repeatedly click on the button.

There are a lot of answers out there about debouncing, maybe you can give a look at lodash debounce, or google for specific React systems like debounce hooks.